# Handling error objects with ng-resource when isArray: true

Tags: angularjs, rest, error-handling, ngresource

I have a resource set up with **isArray: true**, because the backend will return data in an array. However, when the backend returns an error, it will return this as an Object (or a string), and the resource configuration will throw an error:

> Error in resource configuration. Expected response to contain an array but got an object?

Is there a way to handle errors before $resource throws the configuration error? Or should I set my backend so that it returns errors in the correct type? I read somewhere best (RESTful) practice would be to always return (only) objects, and therefore not use **isArray: true** on the client side, but cannot find any supporting evidence now.

What would be the correct way to handle this?

Comment: Does your backend return an HTTP response code other than 200 in case of an error?

Comment: Technically, yes. Were currently working on a few spots where it isnt, but eventually it will return an error code.